# WordPress Database Query

Tags: sql, wordpress

I'm trying to run a SQL query from a WordPress database.  Basically, I need to get the email address of all users from the wp_users table and then check to see if those users have a value that is not null in the row 'agent_name' in the wp_usermeta table. So something like this pseudo code `SELECT user_email FROM 'wp_users' and SELECT agent_name FROM 'wp_usermeta'`.  The goal is to have the query printed out in a csv (that part I can figure out).  You can see an example of the kind of output I'm looking for in this screenshot:

[image]

I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an `INNER JOIN` to achive this:

```
SELECT u.user_email, m.meta_value FROM wp_users u 
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta m ON m.user_id = u.ID && 
           m.meta_key = 'agent_name' && 
           m.meta_value IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Hmm, I just tried it and I'm getting no results with an error 

Uknown column 'm.agent_name' in 'field list'

Comment: @Christian - Oooops, It should be `m.meta_value` in the field list, updated my answer.